# Storing an array of map coordinates into a PHP variable

Tags: php, arrays, loops, google-maps, multidimensional-array

I am trying to grab coordinates from an array to add to a Google map to output my polygons.

And I am running into some difficulty in trying to echo out my array ($ArrayCoords) as a string to store into a variable.

I have this array which consist of multiple lat and lng coordinates as well as a zoom:

```
$ArrayCoords = get_field('Array_Coords');
print_r($ArrayCoords); 

/*   Print out as:

 [draw_map] => Array
            (
                [coords] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [lat] => 38.928713698662
                                [lng] => -94.537423253059
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [lat] => 38.927679421508
                                [lng] => -94.537782669067
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [lat] => 38.928038315258
                                [lng] => -94.53973531723
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [lat] => 38.928171856655
                                [lng] => -94.54069018364
                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [lat] => 38.928215341202
                                [lng] => -94.541194438934
                            )

                        [5] => Array
                            (
                                [lat] => 38.929258624074
                                [lng] => -94.541215896606
                            )

                    )

                    [zoom] => 13
         )
*/
```

I am trying to turn this array to store into a variables ($latLngCoords and $Zoom) which will echo as:

```
echo $latLngCoords;

/*
38.928713698662, -94.537423253059
38.927679421508, -94.537782669067
....and so on..
*/

echo $Zoom;

// 13
```

I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Do you have the actual PHP code? or just the array

Comment: I have updating the code a bit

Comment: Can you show the code to construct polygon?

Comment: @Jagr Thanks. But I figured it out. My answer to my question is below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks to all, I am very sorry if my question seemed unclear :(
but I think I figured out my answer using a while loop:**

```
$Zoom = $ArrayCoords[zoom];
$array = $ArrayCoords[coords];
$arrayCount = count($array) - 1;
//arrayCount is 6, but because of array starting at 0, we need to minus -1

$i=0;
while($i <= $arrayCount)
  {
  $latLngCoords .= $array[$i][lat] . ", " . $array[$i][lng] . "<br>";

  $i++;

  }

echo $latLngCoords;

echo $Zoom;

 //print_r($array);
```